# Better approach for MySQL inner join with condition

Tags: mysql

we've two tables, one is `emp` table having columns `id` and `name`. Another table is Designation having columns `id` and `designation`.

> I want to retrieve `emp.id`, `emp.name`, `Designation.designation` for all the employees having a name starting with letter 'A';

#### I've written following MySQL query

```
select emp.name,emp.id,d.designation from 
emp e inner join Designation d on e.id = d.id 
where Left(e.name,1) = 'A';
```

Is there any better way to deal with this problem?  nested query? union something like that?

Comment: I think you must use (where e.name like 'A%')

Comment: Here you can also use left join because sometime designation may not be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is the recommended way to do this.
You could use a query to retrieve the column `designation`:

```
select e.name, e.id, 
  (select d.designation from Designation d where e.id = d.id) designation 
from emp e
where Left(e.name,1) = 'A';
```

only if the 2 tables have a 1 to 1 relationship.
 
But I don't think that this is an improvement for efficiency or readability.
Also the condition:

```
where Left(e.name,1) = 'A'
```

can be written with the operator `LIKE`:

```
where e.name LIKE 'A%'
```